# Java API for Google Analytics

Tags: java, google-analytics

I've found a great example here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/data_over_time
It uses google.gdata, not google.api. The credentials it is asking for are the following:

```
private static final String USERNAME = "username";
private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
private static final String TABLE_ID = "table_id";
```

Whereas in the google.api, the credentials needed are the following:

```
private static final String KEY_FILE_LOCATION = "yourfile.p12";
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "something@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
```

These two libraries (google.api and google.gdata) seem to be able to do similar things but in fact they are different. What is meant by username, password and table_id in the first scenario? Which is the currently recommended Java API for Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended that you use to [Google Analytics Java client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/#Google_Analytics_API). The example you have pointed to uses the [deprecated Client Login](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/auth/clientlogin).

You should use the recently updated [Hello Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-java) tutorial for a better example of using Java API for Google Analytics.